# Let $T(v_i)=v_i+v_{i-1}$. Find $[T_\beta]$ and $[T_\gamma]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\beta=(v_1,..v_n)$ Let $\gamma=(v_1,v_2-v_1,v_3-v_2,...v_n-v_{n-1})$ be basis of a finite dimensional vector space and $T:V\to V$ where $T(v_1)=v_1$ and $T(v_i)= v_i+v_{i-1}$

I believe the matrix of $Q$ here changes $\gamma$ coordinates to $\beta$ coordinates looks like this for example when $n=4$:
$$Q=\left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
1&-1&0&0\\
0&1&-1&0\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{array} } \right]$$

So from my understanding to find $[T]_\gamma$ all I need to do is apply the transformation to this matrix, I get this new matrix.

$$[T]_\gamma=\left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{array} } \right]$$

And then using this I would find $[T]_\beta$ using this formula $[T]_\beta=Q[T]_\gamma Q^{-1}$

I find $$Q^{-1}=\left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{array} } \right]$$

And then using the formula shown above I find $$[T]_\beta=\left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{array} } \right]$$

> Is this correct?

I'm quite sure that I multiplied the matrices in the correct order and somehow I still end up with $[T]_\gamma=[T]_\beta$ So I'm pretty sure I've got the wrong idea how to to get $[T]_\gamma$ or my original matrix $Q$ is incorrect. Not homework just something I made for practice.

Comment: Shouldn't the $T(v_i)$ be written in terms of $i$ and not $n$?

Comment: I fixed it, it's for i greater then 2 to n. So $T(v_1)=v_1, T(v_2)=v_3+v_2$

Comment: Notice that the subscripts are still wrong.

Comment: That's better. ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by writing $[T]_\beta$ since your linear map $T$ is given in terms of the basis $\beta$:

$$[T]_\beta = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}$$

Now $$[T]_\gamma = [I]_{\gamma, \beta} [T]_\beta [I]_{\beta, \gamma} = Q^{-1}[T]_\beta Q = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1} \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1} \pmatrix{1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}$$

We get

$$[T]_\gamma = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1}$$

which is the same as $[T]_\beta$ since

$$Tv_1 = v_1$$

$$T(v_i - v_{i-1}) = Tv_i - Tv_{i-1} = v_i + v_{i-1} - v_{i-1} - v_{i-2} = (v_i - v_{i-1}) + (v_{i-1} - v_{i-2})$$

so, interestingly, $T$ acts on $\gamma$ the same way it acts on $\beta$.

Comment: See when I saw how T was written I thought it simply meant a transformation on vectors in V. And the way $\gamma$ are defined they are vectors in V. So why can't I apply it to $I_{\beta,\gamma}$?

Comment: @AColoredReptile I'm not sure I understand the question. $[I]_{\beta,\gamma}$ is the matrix representing the identity map $I : V \to V$ with respect to the bases $\gamma$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Why can't I apply the transformation to this matrix? I thought if I did this I would have a matrix which when multiplied by a vector in $\gamma$ would transform that vector and represent it in terms of $\beta$ elements. I can see this isn't true but I guess I don't understand why I can't get $[T]_\gamma$ directly and then find $[T]_\beta$

Comment: @AColoredReptile You would get this:
$$[T]_{\beta, \gamma} = [I]_{\beta, \gamma} [T]_{\gamma}$$
which is precisely the matrix you describe.
Remember that $[T]_{\gamma} = [T]_{\gamma, \gamma}$.

Comment: Are these notations the same $[T]_{\beta}^\gamma=[T]_{\beta,\gamma}$? If so I think I understand.

Comment: @AColoredReptile I believe so, we have $$[Tx]_{\beta} = [T]_{\beta, \gamma} [x]_{\gamma}$$